# Cross-column summary after `summary_rows` with gt

Tags: r, gt

This is a toy example, so the numbers are meaningless, but how would I calculate the summary statistics for `proportion` in the `summary_rows` row of the table per group?

`proportion` is a row-wise calculation, so I can't sum/mean/sd/etc. For `average proportion`, for example, I want to calculate `num`[average] / `items`[average]. I can't figure out how to get a custom function to work for `fns` across groups.

```
exibble_a <-
  exibble %>%
  mutate(items = runif(8,10,20)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(proportion = ifelse(is.na(items / num), 0, items / num)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(fctr, date, time, datetime))

exibble_b = 
  exibble_a %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  gt(rowname_col = "row", groupname_col = "group") %>%
  fmt_missing(columns = everything()) %>%
  fmt_percent(columns = proportion,
              decimals = 2) %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
               columns = c(num,items),
               fns = list(
                 average = ~ mean(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                 total = ~ sum(.,na.rm=TRUE),
                 SD = ~ sd(.,na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
  summary_rows(groups = TRUE,
               columns = proportion,
               fns = list(
                 average = ~ mean(exibble_a$items) / mean(exibble_a$num, 
                                                          na.rm=TRUE)),
               formatter = fmt_percent,
               decimals = 2,
               use_seps = TRUE)

exibble_b
```

Comment: In the data, items and num are the same, so you get proportion as 1

Comment: Do you need `exibble %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(proportion = num/sum(num, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Also, a custom function can be passed as `fns = list(new = ~ yourfun(.))`

Comment: Darn! Sorry, I forgot to change items from num to the runif.

Comment: @akrun: Thanks for the pointer. That question was very helpful. I still can't get the custom functions to work for each group.

Comment: It's okay.  I was not sure if that was a correct dupe.  may be it is related.  thanks